# CSS background image and footer text

Tags: html, css

Working through a tutorial to learn about CSS and I am trying to figure out how some whitespace is being created. When I inspect the page, the whitespace is within the `body` tag. I thought the `body` tag would put all text within the background image. But when I re-size the window there is various degrees of white space created (as you can see in the image).

I would like to create a new row for the `More Text` so that when the screen is re-sized smaller, the row remains below the image--instead of creating the whitespace between. Thanks for any help.

[image]

**html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>

<head>

    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Title</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="page-footer">
        <h1>More text</a></h1>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
h1 a {
    color: #666699;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

body {
    background-image: url('../images/Death_to_stock_photography_wild_6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}

.page-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.page-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
    bottom:0;
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 26pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    height: 5px;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: #666699;
}
```

Comment: with padding? margin?

Comment: issus is with the padding - padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px; remove it and try ..hope it works

Comment: @NagaSaiA still has white space below when I re-size after removing the padding

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to define attributes for a given element for smaller screen.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .myclass{
        myattribute:myvalue; 
    }
}
```

A easier and better solution would be using a third party framework like bootstrap or foundation which has a grid system for responsive design.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at this but wanted to start small first, which seems like more trouble than worth

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your css on codepen:
http://codepen.io/artchibald/pen/KrJdpY

It seems you have a bottom 0 declared in the css, below is the corrected version:

```
h1 a {
    color: #666699;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

body {
    background-image: url('../images/Death_to_stock_photography_wild_6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}

.page-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.page-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
    /* REMOVE THIS--------bottom:0; */
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 26pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    height: 5px;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: #666699;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Archie, but whitespace remains.